# AddDbContext creates 2 instances in 1 request

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I have a ASP.NET core 2.1 app with EF 2 core
I am using the built-in DI
I register my classes like this:
in Startup.cs, in ConfigureServices

```
    var connectionString = this.configuration.GetConnectionString("MYConnection");
     services.AddDbContext<IMyContext, MyContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

     services.AddScoped<IMy1Dao, My1Dao>();
     services.AddScoped<IMy2Dao, My2Dao>();
     services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();
```

I inject the classes like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller, IMyController{      
    private readonly IMyService myService;
    public  MyController(IMyService myService)
    {     
                this.myService = myService;      
    }
    public async Task<List<MyBatchUIDTO>> GetMyBatches([FromBody]List<short> ids)
    {
       return await myService.GetMyBatches(ids);
    }
}
public class MyService : IMyService{
    private readonly IMy1Dao my1Dao;
    private readonly IMy2Dao my2Dao;
    public MyService(IMy1Dao my1Dao, IMy2Dao my2Dao)
    {  
        this.my1Dao = my1Dao;
        this.my2Dao = my2Dao;
    }
}
public  partial class MyContext : DbContext, IMyContext
{   
    public MyContext() { }  
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
    {

}
    //left out DBSET<> details
}
public class My1Dao : IMy1Dao
{
    private IMyContext context
    public My1Dao(IMyContext context)
    {
        this.context = context
    }              
}
public class My2Dao :  IMy2Dao
{
    private IMyContext context
    public My2Dao(IMyContext context)
    {
        this.context = context
    }              
}
```

But I am getting 2 different instances of MyContext in the MyService constructor.
I know this because I hava break point on the MyContext Constructora and it breaks there twice.
Also when  I read from the 2 DAOs  they don't share the returned sets.
Which is what I need them to do.

Comment: Is there any project to reproduce your issue, I made a test with your code, but I fail to reproduce your issue when accessing home controller. Please try to reproduce your issue based on my test [project](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsyeWQ2z51P3hkOt_llkidBfs7qx)

Comment: I just copied your code into  a new project and added a Guid property to your DbContext and assign it a new value in the constructor, it works just fine, all context created in an HTTP request( scope ) have the same instance and the same Guid, besides the Context constructor just hits once

Comment: The constructor for MyContext class doesn't have the base invoke: base(options)